# What's the easiest way to upgrade to 16 from my current situation?

Tags: 12.04, 16.04, upgrade, disk-image

I have an old laptop that doesn't get used frequently but is very important when it does get used.  It's an inspiron 6000 just in case this makes a difference.

I'm currently running 12.04 and that's starting to result in problems, not to mention I think support has ended.

If this old girl can handle 16 I'd like to upgrade to it.  I partitioned my hard drive years ago to try to make these things easier.  I have an external I can save an image to.

Can I just upgrade using a disk image?  Can I skip 14 if I just do a fresh install and abandon everything here?  Will I have trouble when I try to import my files later?

I know I'm a little all over the place.  I'll clean this up as we go if anyone has suggestions for that in comments.

Thanks

Comment: Personally, this is how I would do it:
[1] Make a back up of everything somewhere "outside" your existing drive.
[2] Make yourself a bootable USB with 16.04 on it. 
[3] Change the BIOS to boot from the USB, then run the USB.
[4] This will tell you what will / will not work and what the performance will be like.
[5] Decide !

16.04 has Unity and is much more likely to run than 17.10 as it seems there are small number of users having some Wayland issues.

Comment: You're welcome....
But, be aware, this would be a new install, so you may have some post install work to do, like re-setting up your email, any third party stuff you have that you've taken from the Repository, any shortcuts you have, that sort of thing.
But, that may not be a bad thing and may help with performance. Also, as you re-add stuff, you'll know what goes wrong and what may have caused it.

Comment: I'd do it as @Piloti has already suggested, but do I `sudo dpkg -l >filesomewhere` (list packages installed) to refer to if I wonder what app I used for ...  I'll give the normal route you probably already realize.  12.04LTS can be release-upgraded to 14.04LTS which can be done via 'image' [or web] but its a pain unless you only use 'main' repo software; and even then I'd release-upgrade using web.  From 14.04LTS you can then release-upgrade to 16.04LTS which will attempt to keep your apps (ie. saving you from re-installing them).  don't forget to backup !

Comment: I agree that a fresh install is the best in this case. Probably faster and easier than a two-step upgrade, that might not work anyway. But 'Try Ubuntu' live before installing it. It may work better with an Ubuntu community flavour  (i386 alias 32-bit version) with a light desktop environment for your old computer, Lubuntu, Ubuntu Budgie, Ubuntu MATE or Xubuntu.

Comment: Considering all the changes I would just go with 17.10. If you do not like gnome-shell, go with k/x/lubuntu . IMHO resistance is futile, you can not avoid gnome-shell forever =) People are resistant to change and IMHO Ubuntu has done a nice job customizing gnome-shell.

Answer (score 2):

Back up everything you need to keep and do a clean install. In my experience a clean install is always the best way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Can I suggest you install Lubuntu? I had Ubuntu running on an older server and it was "okay" regarding speed. When Ubuntu went to 17.10 I decided to try a lighter version of Ubuntu--called Lubuntu. Lubuntu works very nicely on the older machine and it's much faster in response times. When you install Lubuntu you have several choices of dealing with the hdd and partitions. You can choose to do a completely fresh install, which is what I would do once I backed up my data; or, if you really want to keep the previous OS you can install the Lubuntu side-by-side with the old.

Comment: If you’re looking for something that “works”; try arch it’s not “new user” friendly at all but it’s very good especially on older systems.